# Union all rows and unknown number of columns in Pandas df into one column

Tags: python, pandas

I produce a df with an unknow number of columns. The end result I want is 1 column with all the not null values in that column.

What I have:

| 0 | 1 | 2 | n |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| null | null | null | null |
| ["3337eb01-b5b4-4faf-b28c-adc27daafb41","6f237308-0858-488b-b1e0-cd19a92f6da9"] | null | null | null |
| ["644c94a5-6d24-469f-bff6-70ad87751567","1590d981-ece4-41ed-9cd9-25c1ba91cbeb"] | null | null | null |
| ["879a225b-ffb9-4aa3-88d2-019feec50884","8548ea5c-c441-4d3d-81ed-a9310c509083"] | ["a89156ef-8999-4f57-9061-4d6a8b7d6eab","36dff979-7f2a-4171-bc58-75d9e28866d8"] | ["e238389d-0de3-4e71-9069-c84d30f2ca09","e5961ae2-734d-4b1d-b1bf-0e494d913a33"] | null |
| null | null | null | null |
| ["2fe96d20-dc59-45fd-93dc-382c553d89ae","1666bf9e-719f-48d0-839e-daa35960edd0"] | ["45a012d2-6a4d-43f0-837a-9d9abf281844","9707b678-3ecd-463f-8058-b94a7ad1232e"] | null | null |

What I need is:

| 0 |
| --- |
| ["3337eb01-b5b4-4faf-b28c-adc27daafb41","6f237308-0858-488b-b1e0-cd19a92f6da9"] |
| ["644c94a5-6d24-469f-bff6-70ad87751567","1590d981-ece4-41ed-9cd9-25c1ba91cbeb"] |
| ["879a225b-ffb9-4aa3-88d2-019feec50884","8548ea5c-c441-4d3d-81ed-a9310c509083"] |
| ["a89156ef-8999-4f57-9061-4d6a8b7d6eab","36dff979-7f2a-4171-bc58-75d9e28866d8"] |
| ["e238389d-0de3-4e71-9069-c84d30f2ca09","e5961ae2-734d-4b1d-b1bf-0e494d913a33"] |
| ["2fe96d20-dc59-45fd-93dc-382c553d89ae","1666bf9e-719f-48d0-839e-daa35960edd0"] |
| ["45a012d2-6a4d-43f0-837a-9d9abf281844","9707b678-3ecd-463f-8058-b94a7ad1232e"] |

The code that produces the df:

```
def powerset(iterable):
"powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
s = list(iterable)
return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(n,n+1))

combdf = []
unique_mk = input_df['key'].unique()
for unique_loop in unique_mk:
  loop_df = input_df[input_df['key']==unique_loop]
  #display(loop_df)
  #for res in res: 
    #combdf = pd.DataFrame(res)
  res = [dc['id'].to_list() for e in powerset(loop_df.index) if (dc:=loop_df.reindex(e))['amount'].sum() == 0 and dc.shape[0] <= n]
  combdf.append(res)

comb_df = pd.DataFrame(combdf)
```

input_df looks like:

| id | key | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | XYZ | 100 |
| 456 | XYZ | -100 |
| 789 | ABC | 50 |

Comment: NameError: name 'input_df' is not defined

Comment: input_df would be 3 columns: id (unique), key (non unique), amount

Comment: Does the row order of the final DataFrame count?

Comment: no, I just need all the id pairs

Comment: `df.stack().to_frame(name=[0])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `stack`:

```
>>> df.stack().reset_index(drop=True)

0    ["3337eb01-b5b4-4faf-b28c-adc27daafb41","6f237...
1    ["644c94a5-6d24-469f-bff6-70ad87751567","1590d...
2    ["879a225b-ffb9-4aa3-88d2-019feec50884","8548e...
3    ["a89156ef-8999-4f57-9061-4d6a8b7d6eab","36dff...
4    ["e238389d-0de3-4e71-9069-c84d30f2ca09","e5961...
5    ["2fe96d20-dc59-45fd-93dc-382c553d89ae","1666b...
6    ["45a012d2-6a4d-43f0-837a-9d9abf281844","9707b...
dtype: object
```